# How to show a hover popup with SWT StyledText

Tags: java, swt, mousehover, styledtext

I am using SWT's `StyledText` and I am wondering how I would detect if the user hovers over a word for more then 3 seconds. An example of what I mean is how Eclipse has a popup that shows, when you hover over a text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a 'mouse track listener' to listen for mouse hover events. However you can't set the hover time for this:

```
control.addMouseTrackListener(MouseTrackListener)
```

`MouseTrackListener` has three events - `mouseEnter`, `mouseExit` and `mouseHover`.

Answer (score 3):

While you can implementet text hover yourself, with a `MouseTrackListener` like suggested by [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449), you can also use the JFace [`TextViewer`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Ftext%2FTextViewer.html).

The `TextViewer` provides a higher-level abstraction for text hover. With its `setTextHover()` methods you can set a callback, that is informed when a text hover for a certain region should be shown.

This is also the method that is used by Eclipse text editors.

Answer (score 0):

I believe those are tooltips that appear when you hover over a text for e.g. in Java editor. See [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fwindow%2FToolTip.html) for tooltip doc and [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.eclipse.jface.window.ToolTip) for examples on how real production code uses eclipse tooltips.